# Windows server 2008 uptime

Tags: windows-server-2008, high-availability, reliability

I am deploying a critical care client-server application on Windows server 2008. We have a requirement saying the server must be running without restart for atleast 6 months. Although we ensure this reliability on the software which we are developing, I am not sure if windows server 2008 promises this uptime. Can anybody here help me on the following questions:

1) Can windows server 2008 R2 run without restart for 6 months?

2) If it can run for 6 months, is there any know resources penalty?

3) Is there any stranded mitigation provided by Win server 2008 to ensure this (some kind of OS handle leaks cleanup, memory cleanup etc?

4) What is the best way to enusre high availability on win server 2008.

Well please note some of the constrains:

1) I cant move to any other OS as Win server 2008 is part of our requirement.

2) Techniques like a additional standby/backup server is not feasible

Answer (score 0):

1. I know of at least on Win2008 machine which has been running since
   2008 (not production!)
2. There are no resource penalties in Win2008 itself
3. Buggy apps will do buggy things. Its arguable that the OS should not
   do anything about leaks.
4. Don't put buggy apps on them.

Note if you want 100% uptime, you can also never apply Windows Updates. Set a reasonable limit which allows some hours downtime a year: 9 hours downtime/year is 99.99% uptime. Not bad.